# State of a smart contract updated, but no transaction listed on etherscan

Tags: transactions, ethereum, chainlink, etherscan

I'm looking at a contract on etherscan and I can see that a variable has been updated, but looking at the list of transactions it doesn't seem that any transaction has modified the state.

[Let's take this transaction for example.](https://etherscan.io/address/0x5f4ec3df9cbd43714fe2740f5e3616155c5b8419)

We can see exactly 4 transactions:
[image: ETH/USD]

Now, using the `read contract` functionality of Etherscan, we can see the various responses of `phaseAggregators`, defined in the smart contract as such:

```js
mapping(uint16 => AggregatorV2V3Interface) public phaseAggregators;
```

We can add 0,1,2,3,4,5 etc and still get responses.

However, only 2 elements were added to the mapping from the 4 transactions! (marked in green):
[Transaction List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXbM3.png)

But using the etherscan "read contract" functionality, I have found that the phaseAggregators mapping has 5 elements.

In my understanding there should be 3 more transactions. Where are they?

Is it possible that etherscan is not showing all the transactions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Etherscan, there is a second, although oddly named, list of transactions called `internal transactions`. [Internal Transactions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6429/normal-transactions-vs-internal-transactions-in-etherscan) are transactions that have been initiated by another contract.

So you could imagine the flow like this:

Person -> Contract A -> Contract B

Contract A's transaction to Contract B would show up as an "internal transaction".

[This can be a very long list.](https://etherscan.io/address/0x5f4ec3df9cbd43714fe2740f5e3616155c5b8419/advanced#internaltx)